# Evolution Calendar without email account attached

Tags: evolution

I have been using Evolution for it's calendar for some time now.
But every time I open the calendar, it asks for my email password.
So today, I had enough, I deleted my email account from evolution(I use a different program for emails) but now I can't open evolution because it wants to add an email account.

Is there a work arround for this? Since I can't manage my calendar anymore(unless I add an email account).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been struggling with this for a while too, I've seen this as an [idea on Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/9885/), but still just an idea.

I suggest you try using [Sunbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/), but otherwise, I don't know if there's a solution to this problem.

Comment: I saw the idea, but I like evolution because I just have to click my clock to see what's up.
And it must be compatible with my Google account, since I have to share with my android calendar.
But thanks for the reply. Maybe someone has a work arround, if not, I will select your answer in a few hours.

Comment: Hope you find a workaround. (if you find one, I'll go back to evoution) :)

Comment: since no other replies, your answer seems to be the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use Evolution without setting an e-mail account (go figure). However, Evolution does not check if you give it an actual account during set up. Just set in a dummy address and point all servers to 127.0.0.1. Also, untick the *Check e-mail every x minutes* box.

Comment: Thanks, it has been 5 years since I asked this and in the mean time my knowledge about things improved. I also stopped using Ubuntu and gmail. I hope your answer helps others though.